# Alpha clip doesn't work with Color Ramp

Tags: eevee-render-engine, transparency

[image]

I want to do that with alpha clip, but I don't know how.

This is with alpha clip

[image: Alpha Clip]

This is with alpha blend

[image: Alpha blend]